# Why printing char * with %s prints "(null)"?

Tags: c

This is my code:

```
char *x;
char *y;

printf("x:");
scanf("%s", x);

printf("y:");
scanf("%s", y);

printf("x: %s, y: %s\n", x, y);
return 0;
```

when i run it:

```
x:hello 
y:world
x: hello, y: (null)
```

Why I'am getting (null) instead of the "world"?

Thanks for help

Comment: You never allocated any space for `x` or `y`, so they're undefined.  The behavior is unspecified.  Your `scanf` calls are writing to whatever unknown memory locations `x` and `y` happen to have in them.  It could be anything.

Comment: You have not allocated any memory to `*x` or `*y` and `scanf()` will not do it for you. The code has *undefined behaviour*. The MS compiler kindly prints `(null)` but some will just let the program crash. With undefined behaviour the result is not even consistent.

Comment: `char *x` -> `char x[100]`.

Answer (score 2):

You never allocate space for the strings. They point to some random garbage value.
Use `malloc()` to dynamically allocate space for your strings or use a `char[]` for automatic storage.

Here is an example with automatic allocated space:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char x[20]; // space for 19 characters and a null-terminator
    char y[20];

    printf("x:");
    scanf("%s", x);

    printf("y:");
    scanf("%s", y);
    printf("x: %s, y: %s\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `malloc` for allocating small fixed size buffers is overkill

Comment: That's why i said he may use `char[]`

Comment: You should insist that `malloc` here is a bad idea and that it's bad practice. Otherwise beginners might think that they _actually_  should use `malloc` like that

Comment: Now the explanation doesn't really match the code

Comment: The code will be robust with buffer overflow protection: `scanf("%19s", x);` There is space for 19 characters, not 20.

Answer (score 1):

> Why printing char * with %s prints “(null)”?

To answer the question of why you get that `(null)`, I'm guessing you're using glibc.

[Glibc's printf() does that when passed a null pointer](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Other-Output-Conversions.html). E.g. this prints "hello (null)":

```
char *a = "hello", *b = NULL;
printf("%s %s\n", a, b);
```

Then again, if you try this:

```
printf("%s\n", b);
```

[gcc optimizes it to `puts(b)`](https://blogs.gnome.org/desrt/2007/10/01/gcc-feature-breaks-glibc-feature/), which *doesn't* do the same, but happily accesses the pointer, usually crashing. [According to the gcc developers](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15685), that's ok, since really, you're wrong in passing that NULL to `printf()`, and anyway, it might not work with other C libraries.

Also, if you were to check the return values of your `scanf()` calls, you'd see the second one returns 0, indicating that it can't complete the conversion. That's what glibc's `scanf()` appears to do when passed a NULL pointer as the destination of a `%s`. Well, that's what it looks like anyway, I didn't find that in the manual. Again, don't count on it.

So why do you have a null pointer in `y`? Because you left it uninitialized and that's the value you happened to get. Of course, when doing that, the behaviour is totally undefined, but in this case appears to match what you would have got if you'd done `char *y = NULL;` instead.

There's already a fine answer about what you *should have done*, so I won't go there.